# VBA_ Loop through a table corresponding to another table loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have the code below which updates some values in my worksheet table based on input values on the user form. This works with the code below perfectly.

This is what I want to add to this code: I have another table on my worksheet, with values that are dependent to these values and i want them to be looped and updated. on the screenshot below the code as you see, I want to loop through column 2 of table on the left and `If tbl2.DataBodyRange(y, 2).Value = Combo_spl1load.Value` (for example "PL1.St.HRP1"), get all corresponding values from the column 1, here "PL2.St.PR1" and "PL2.St.PR1". Then loop through the first column of the other table on the right to find the similar values ("PL2.St.PR1" and "PL2.St.PR2") and change the corresponding values in the column 2 of this second table (which are now 320 and 176) to "not defined".

```
Private Sub but_spl1update_Click()

    
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL2_steel")
    
    Dim tbl2 As ListObject
    Set tbl2 = sh2.ListObjects("Tbl_spl2elements")

    Dim x2 As Long
    x2 = FirstEmptyColumnRow(tbl2, 1)
 
     For y = 1 To x2
            If tbl2.DataBodyRange(y, 2).Value = Combo_spl1load.Value Then
            tbl2.DataBodyRange(y, 3).Value = Txt_spl1totalgwp2.Value
            tbl2.DataBodyRange(y, 5).Value = val(tbl2.DataBodyRange(y, 4).Value) * val(Txt_spl1totalgwp2.Value)
            End If
     Next y
     

 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me to not mention that the code is fine for the first part. I updated my post

Comment: `x2 = FirstEmptyColumnRow(tbl2, 1)` how does this run before you've assigned `tbl2`?

Comment: It was just an error for the las minute editing my post here. The code runs error free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub but_spl1update_Click()
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet, tbl2 As ListObject, tblProd As ListObject
    Dim rw As Range, v, id, rwP As Range
    
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL2_steel")
    Set tbl2 = sh2.ListObjects("Tbl_spl2elements")
    Set tblProd = sh2.ListObjects("Tbl_spl2elements")
    
    v = Combo_spl1load.Value

    For Each rw In tbl2.DataBodyRange.Rows
        If rw.Cells(2).Value = v Then
            rw.Cells(3).Value = Txt_spl1totalgwp2.Value
            rw.Cells(5).Value = rw.Cells(4).Value * Val(Txt_spl1totalgwp2.Value)
            id = rw.Cells(1).Value
            'check second table for id from col 1
            For Each rwP In tblProd.DataBodyRange.Rows
                If rwP.Cells(1).Value = id Then
                    rwP.Cells(2).Value = "not defined"
                End If
            Next rwP
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Note to make your code more robust, instead of hard-coding column positions you can look them up from the column header.  eg:

```
Dim idColPos as Long
'...
idColPos = tbl2.ListColumns("Unique Identifier Code").Index
'...
'...
id = rw.Cells(idColPos).Value
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works perfectly. I did not know how to nest the For loops. 
Regarding the code improvement that you suggest, I do understand that it is better to define for example columns based on header but i sometimes change the headers and dont want them to be dependent to the header titles. 
Thanks again and all the bests...

Comment: Good to hear it's working out.